# Pic on button when music is playing

Tags: ios, swift

I'm making a radio app and i was thinking ...
How can add a picture inside the button(radio canal) which will means the music is currently playing in specific canal ?
I would like to add it in left- up corner of the button.

I'm soryy bout my english i'm still learning. 
Hope You will understand.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: more important is code what you have tried and what you're stuck at or what the error is. so we can help you.

Comment: yeah, i know i made second picture for background so.. when it is selected it will change.. but i don't know how to do it  without making another picture so i ask how..

Comment: So I guess you did set a picture a UIImageView and you have a Button. And now you want to press the Button to change the Image. Right?

Comment: I have read you question 10 times now and I guess you want to change the image of the button itself, then this would be the code

Comment: actually no, i dont want to change the image i would like to add some small icon inside it which will means that music is playing. Something like this: http://postimg.org/image/bpx5iuyqt/

Comment: see my edited answer

Comment: you need to have different imges for the different states you want to have

Comment: for example a picture that shows that the player is in play mode and a picture for stop mode

Comment: i have edited it once more. like this you have now the possibility to check if the button is in play mode and change it back to stop mode

Comment: i really need to ? there is no way to do it in different way ?

Comment: no this is the only way

Comment: you can't add just icons to the image you have. you need to change the whole image and need to have images for every state you want

Comment: ugh my english is bad. I did it ...I have already two view controllers , one is for stream and one is for radio stations .. for example i pick one station (button) and then i go to stream view controller .. now music is playing and i go back to my 1 view controller ( the first one with the stations)  and now.. ON THIS view controller i have buttons with radios and i want to see which radio is currently playing.

Comment: that is way past the possibilties of stackoverflow. this is a site to help you with errors in your code. not explain you how to code. and english is a fundamental in coding... get used to it...

Comment: i have explained you in my answer what you wanted to know in your question. so far this question is answered.

Answer (score 0):

Set a Action function for your `UIButton` and Outlet for the same `UIButton`. Within its IBAction func you change the call the `setImage` func of the Button to change the Image.

```
@IBOutlet weak var yourButtonOutlet: UIButton!   

var isPlay: Bool = false

@IBAction func yourButton(sender: AnyObject) {

        if isPlay != true {
               let image = UIImage(named: "play.png") {
               yourButtonOutlet.setImage(image, forState: .Normal)
               isPlay = true

        } else {
               let image = UIImage(named: "stop.png") {
               yourButtonOutlet.setImage(image, forState: .Normal)
               isPlay = false
        }         
}
```

Also we are checking if the Button is using the "play" state currently to be able to set it back to "stop" mode (set the pictures to the desired mode).